# How to draw scale-independent arrows with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotations, arrows

I have drawn a trajectory plot in python using matplotlib of a boat like so:

[image]

Now I want to add some arrows, like wind direction, true heading etc. However I want the arrows to have the same size no matter which zoom-level the plot is at. I tried matplotlib.pyplot.arrow, however there I have to define the length of the arrows. I could make matplotlib.pyplot.arrow work, but then I'd have to get the height and width of the plot, and scale my arrows accordingly, so I wondered if there was a better way to obtain scale-independent arrows for these points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate` instead. See [the docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate) for more info!

Basically, set the `xycoords` parameter to `"axes fraction"` to instruct it to plot using relative fraction of the axes itself rather than data coordinates.

Comment: Hello,
So I tried your solution, but I am not entirely satisfied, because when I use `axes fraction` and I zoom in, the arrows stay at the places relative to the axes (Which is what `axes fraction` is supposed to do. But I want the _Scaling_ of the arrows to stay the same relative to the plot. The position shall of course be variable...
I realize this is a lot to ask for, so perhaps using arrows and just play around with the scaling factors by hand and accepting that you loose the ability to zoom is the way to go...

Comment: Does it work if you set both the ```xy``` and the ```xytext``` parameters using axes fractions? The first of those specifies the axes-coordinate location of the annotated thing, while the second specifies the relative location of the the other end of the annotating arrow. It's in the docs again!