# How to add annotation arrows to legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotate, arrows

I have a trajectory of some robot, together with some arrows describing parameters of the robot. Just like so:
[Robot Trajectory with annotation arrows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZtv6.png)
(because of my lack of reputation, I cannot add the picture directly)

The question is: How can I display the annotation arrows together with the lines in the legend?

I use annotation arrows in order to draw the arrows as per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57221054/how-to-draw-scale-independent-arrows-with-matplotlib) in a loop to draw arrows for every point.
Here is the code for one of my annotations:

```py
an = ax.annotate('', xy=xy_tuple, xytext=xy_texttuple, label=labelString, arrowprops=dict(color=arrowcolor, arrowstyle=aStyle))
```

And just as a reference, I use the plotting function like so:

```py
    # plot Local x-y axis
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
    ln1 = ax1.plot(x, y, '-o', label='Location of the last 48h')
    ax1.set_ylabel('Local North (m)')
    ax1.set_xlabel('Local East (m)')
    ax1.grid()
    fig.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
    lns = ln1
    labs = [l.get_label() for l in lns]
    ax1.legend(lns, labs, loc='best')
```

So how can I add the annotate labels (given by `labelString`) to my legend?

Comment: See https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8236 which also has a solution in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, this is an open issue which was found with matplotlib. The developers wanted to fix this issue, but according to this [discussion](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/10688) on the matplotlib developerboard, an solution was implemented but did not pass to the final version and is now closed (although it is a pretty cool solution imho).

Give an line and two annotations, my solution now looks like so. Of course this is not nearly as nice:

```py
ax1.legend([ln1, an1.arrow_patch, an2.arrow_patch], (ln1.get_label(), an1.get_label(), an2.get_label()))
```

Resulting in the following [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duuV6.png)